# Heroku, triggering a deploy, after installing buildpacks

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, heroku-cli

I just added a buildpack for my heroku application.

It said that on the next deploy, your app will also install the dependencies that your module needs to run.

So i didn't know if this is automatically or if i have to enter a command.

I went to the directory of my project on my local computer and typed these:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Changes made"
git push heroku master
```

When i entered the commit command, i got this message:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

When i entered the push command, i got this message:
I got a message that `everything is up-to-date`.

When i type `git status` i get:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So i went to my app and still it is not working.

So what do i have to do in order for heroku to install the dependencies for my app to run properly?

Comment: What was the output from the `commit`? What's the current `status`?

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question.

Comment: So you don't appear to have actually *changed* anything in your code. When you say *"added a buildpack"*, what did you actually *do*?

Comment: Some time heroku takes a few minutes before completely deploy the app, that's because it needs time to install all the packages which is done automatically.

Comment: Now i did not change my code. What i did was follow the anser to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009016/error-while-excuting-chrome-without-headless-on-heroku

Comment: So that's **not** something that you can commit and push, it's not in your codebase. Is there a restart button in Heroku or whatever pipeline is pushing to it?

Comment: Yes, i was just wondering, when the changes to my app are going to take effect? After all, heroku said that "on the next deploy, your app will also install the dependencies that your module needs to run."

Comment: Yes, that's right, *"on the next deploy"*. That may be triggered by you pushing code, but that will require an actual change to your codebase (or `--allow-empty` when you commit, but I really wouldn't recommend that). I'd also expect your CI/CD or Heroku itself to be able to trigger a rerun.

Comment: Maybe i should just add an empty string variable to my code?

Comment: Also, to trigger the deploy.. Wil the commands i posted here work? I know stupid question, but i have no experience either with git, nor with heroku. I mean these commands are fine right, no additional ones are required.

Comment: Making changes just so you can commit just so you can push just so you can rerun the build seems silly. Look for options in Heroku or your CI/CD to rerun on the existing commit.