# Heroku - rerun app on the existing commit

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, heroku-cli

I had to install a buildpack on the heroku website for my app.
I followed the answer to this question:
[Error while excuting chrome without headless on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009016/error-while-excuting-chrome-without-headless-on-heroku)

It says that "on the next deploy, your app will also install the dependencies that your module needs to run."

I tried to redeploy my code without any changes to it, using:

```
git add .
git commit -am "Changes"
git push heroku master
```

But because i don't have any changes to my code it will not let me.
So can i rerun the application on the existing commit?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a ssh tunnel into your Heroku dyno by running the following command in your terminal and then rerun your app manually:

`$ heroku ps:exec`

Or you can run the following commands:

```
$ git commit -m "Heroku Exec" --allow-empty
$ git push heroku master
$ git reset HEAD^
```

Comment: `heroku ps:exec` doesn't make any sense here, but the second part should work.